# Assign values to NSMutable Array within for loop

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to write a method for a new class called "word", which is a subclass of NSString. I want a method that will accept a NSString containing a single character and return the the place within the word of every instance of that string. I have this so far:

```
@implementation Word
    -(NSMutableArray *)placeOfLetter: (NSString *)letterAsked;{
        NSUInteger *len=(NSUInteger *)[self length];
        int y=0;
        char letter=(char)letterAsked; 

        for (NSUInteger *x=0; x<len; x++) {
                if ([self characterAtIndex:*x]==letter){
                     [matchingLetters insertObject:x atIndex:y];
                     y++;
                }
        }
    }     
@end
```

however, xcode is telling me that I cannot put x as a the parameter for insertObject, because the "implicit conversion from NSUInteger to id is disallowed. How can I get around this?

Comment: What you put into an NSMutableArray must be an Objective-C object.  An int is not an object.  An NSNumber is an object, if you wish to use that.  Or you can use a regular C array of int.

Comment: (Has absolutely nothing to do with being in a `for` loop.)

Comment: is a NSUinteger not an Objective-C object?

Comment: No - NSUInteger is a primitive type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is stemming mostly from your treating `NSUInteger` as a pointer; you have some other casting problems as well. Try the following:

- Instead of taking a full string for the `letterAsked` argument, then getting a `char` out of it, just get a `char` (or `unichar`) as your argument to begin with. You avoid the `letter = (char)letterAsked` conversion altogether.
- Don't make `len` a pointer. You may not need to declare `len` at all. Consider writing your `for` loop like:

  ```
  for(NSUInteger x = 0; x < [self length]; x++) { // ...
  ```

  This also helps you in the `-characterAtIndex:` call; you no longer need to dereference `x` in order to get the character.
- Like Hot Licks said in the comments, use an NSNumber if you want a position inside an NSArray; you need numbers to be class instances to go in an NSArray instance. You can create an NSNumber out of `x` like this:

  ```
  NSNumber * foundPosition = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:x];
  ```
- Consider just using NSMutableArray's `-addObject:` method, rather than keeping track of `y` and incrementing it each time. You'll get the same result.

Comment: NSNumber is a great class. Use it!

Comment: If I were to take these suggestions, would my parameter for -addObject: be foundPosition or (*foundPosition)? Wouldn't I be declaring found position as a pointer, and therefore need to dereference it?

Comment: Just `foundPosition`. It would be a pointer, yes, but **all Objective-C objects are pointers** - the compiler actually yells at you if you try to handle objects as static values in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

[`NSUInteger` is a `typedef` for either `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`, depending on your platform.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html)  It is not an object type.  So when you declare `NSUInteger *x=0`, you're declaring `x` as a pointer-to-unsigned-integer, and initializing it to null.

The `insertObject:atIndex:` requires an `NSUInteger`, not an `NSUInteger*`, as its `index` argument.

Just take out the `*` from the `for` statement and the `characterAtIndex:` message.

You do have other problems in your method also, like casting `letterAsked` to a `char` instead of getting the character out of it using `characterAtIndex:` and declaring `len` as a pointer.